# What’s the difference between autoplay and autorun?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, autorun

Does autoplay in settings>devices is the same thing as autorun that allows programs with autorun.inf on USB stick to install automatically?

Comment: refer to this http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-autoplay-and-autorun

Answer (score 8):

#### What’s the difference between autoplay and autorun?

> - AutoRun is a technology used to start some programs automatically when a CD or another media is inserted into a computer. The main
>   purpose of AutoRun is to provide a software response to hardware
>   actions that a user starts on a computer.
> - AutoPlay is a Windows feature that lets a user select which program starts when a specific type of media, such as music CDs, or DVDs
>   containing photos, is inserted. During AutoPlay, the Autorun.inf file
>   from the media is also parsed. This file (if available) specifies
>   additional commands that will be displayed in the AutoPlay menu. Many
>   companies use this functionality to help initiate their installers.

Changes were made in Windows 7 and later to prevent malware:

> AutoPlay will no longer support the AutoRun functionality for non-optical removable media. In other words, AutoPlay will still work for CD/DVDs but it will no longer work for USB drives. For example, if an infected USB drive is inserted on a machine then the AutoRun task will not be displayed. This will block the increasing social engineer threat highlighted in the SIR. The dialogs below highlight the difference that users will see after this change. Before the change, the malware is leveraging AutoRun (box in red) to confuse the user. After the change, AutoRun will no longer work, so the AutoPlay options are safe.

Source: [AutoRun changes in Windows 7 – Microsoft Security Response Center](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7/)

See also: [Enabling and Disabling AutoRun - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/autoplay-reg?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Hard to believe no one ever asked this before.

Comment: @Moab Back in the XP days, you either knew the difference or didn't know one (or both) of the names. Now that they're more obscure, more people are likely to have heard of both but not know the distinction.